# vb.net Task.Factory multiple tasks needed?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

Is this asynchronous programming correct ?
Since this is my first time using TAP, I want to make sure I do it correctly from the beginning.

I want to fill a table from a ODBC database and afterwards read some files and extract values out of it, without freezing my UI.

Why do I need to run `OdbcDataAdapter` and the file reading as `tasks` if I run the whole `Function` as a `task` in my UI Sub ?  Otherwise it blocks my UI. thread.

**UI Code**

```
Private Async Sub frmOfsList_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Show
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch 'query time
    sw.Start()

    DataGridView1.Visible = False
    Label2.Visible = False

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Await OFS.GetJobList 'async method

    sw.Stop()
    Label2.Text = "Query time: " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds & "s"

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1    'color days until prodution date
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value < 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
        End If
    Next

    DataGridView1.Visible = True    'show grid
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    Label2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

**Async Function**

```
Public Shared Async Function GetJobList() As Task(Of DataTable)

    Dim dq As Char = """"
    Dim con As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(constr)
    con.Open()

    'get data from OFS 
    Dim cmd As String = "SELECT p1.ProductionOrder, p1.Project, p1.ProductionDate, p1.Item, p1.Revision, p1.PlannedQty FROM " &
                            dq & "OFS460" & dq & "." & dq & "dbo" & dq & "." & dq & "tblProductionOrders" & dq & " p INNER JOIN " & dq & "OFS460" & dq & "." & dq & "dbo" &
                                   dq & "." & dq & "tblProductionOrders" & dq & " p1 ON p.ProductionOrder = p1.ProductionOrder WHERE (p.Task=2820 AND p.StatusID=4) AND (p1.Task=2830 AND (p1.StatusID=1 OR p1.StatusID=2 OR p1.StatusID=3)) ORDER BY p1.ProductionDate"

    Dim adapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd, con)
    Dim datatable As New DataTable("JobList")

    'fil table with job data async
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                    adapter.Fill(datatable)
                                End Sub)

    'add columns to table
    datatable.Columns.Add("Length", GetType(Double))
    datatable.Columns.Add("Outside Dia", GetType(Double))
    Dim proddate As DateTime
    datatable.Columns.Add("Days until").SetOrdinal(3)

    'calculate days
    For j As Integer = 0 To datatable.Rows.Count - 1
        proddate = datatable(j)(2)
        datatable.Rows(j)(3) = proddate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days
    Next

    'Get length and diameter for each part
    Dim searchpath As String = My.Settings.g250path
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()

                                    Dim files As String()
                                    Dim filetext As String
                                    For i As Integer = 0 To datatable.Rows.Count - 1

                                        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(searchpath, "*" & datatable.Rows(i)("Item") & "*") 'get file by item#
                                        If files.Length > 0 Then
                                            filetext = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(files(0)) 'read file

                                            datatable.Rows(i)("Length") = ProgramManager.GetValue(filetext, "I_R872", 7).ToString   'extract values
                                            datatable.Rows(i)("Outside Dia") = ProgramManager.GetValue(filetext, "I_R877", 7).ToString
                                        End If

                                    Next i
                                End Sub)

    Return datatable

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `Async-Await`. You should use `Task.Run`, instead.

And you only need to get out of the UI thread once for the "heavy work" and return when done.

Try this:

```
Public Shared Function GetJobList() As DataTable

    Dim dq As Char = """"
    Dim con As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(constr)
    con.Open()

    'get data from OFS 
    Dim cmd As String = "SELECT p1.ProductionOrder, p1.Project, p1.ProductionDate, p1.Item, p1.Revision, p1.PlannedQty FROM ""OFS460"".""dbo"".""tblProductionOrders"" p INNER JOIN ""OFS460"".""dbo"".""tblProductionOrders"" p1 ON p.ProductionOrder = p1.ProductionOrder WHERE (p.Task=2820 AND p.StatusID=4) AND (p1.Task=2830 AND (p1.StatusID=1 OR p1.StatusID=2 OR p1.StatusID=3)) ORDER BY p1.ProductionDate"

    Dim adapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd, con)
    Dim datatable As New DataTable("JobList")

    'fil table with job data async
    adapter.Fill(datatable)

    'add columns to table
    datatable.Columns.Add("Length", GetType(Double))
    datatable.Columns.Add("Outside Dia", GetType(Double))
    Dim proddate As DateTime
    datatable.Columns.Add("Days until").SetOrdinal(3)

    'calculate days
    For j As Integer = 0 To datatable.Rows.Count - 1
        proddate = datatable(j)(2)
        datatable.Rows(j)(3) = proddate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days
    Next

    'Get length and diameter for each part
    Dim searchpath As String = My.Settings.g250path

    Dim files As String()
    Dim filetext As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To datatable.Rows.Count - 1
        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(searchpath, "*" & datatable.Rows(i)("Item") & "*") 'get file by item#
        If files.Length > 0 Then
            filetext = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(files(0)) 'read file
            datatable.Rows(i)("Length") = ProgramManager.GetValue(filetext, "I_R872", 7).ToString   'extract values
            datatable.Rows(i)("Outside Dia") = ProgramManager.GetValue(filetext, "I_R877", 7).ToString
        End If
    Next i

    Return datatable

End Function
```

And invoke it like this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Await Task.Run(AddressOf OFS.GetJobList1)
```

This way, the `OFS.GetJobList1` function will be scheduled to execute on a thread pool thread and, when completed, the execution will resume on the caller sub/function and the return value of `Task.Run` (which is the return value of `OFS.GetJobList1` wrapped with a `Task(Of DataTable)`) will be unwrapped and assigned to `DataGridView1.DataSource`.

Comment: Try the revised answer.

Comment: I did it like  `DataGridView1.DataSource = Await Task.Run(Of DataTable)(Function()
                                                                    Return OFS.GetJobList1
                                                                End Function)` and it works. But in what point is this better than my solution, if you could explain to me real quick ?

Comment: I went with `DataGridView1.DataSource = Await Task.Run(AddressOf OFS.GetJobList1)` and added a brief explanation to the answer.